# Error with Ned Consistency in hetvnet simulation

Tags: parameters, veins, simulte

I am using instant veins 5.1-i1 with simuLTe and tried to import veins_hetvnet project. Some errors occured after build project because ltenic is implemented in lte.stack (and not in lte.stack.phy like in instant veins 5.0-aplha2). I changed the path in "import" but I still have an error:

'd2dCapable' = no such parameter

```
lteNic: <nicType> like ILteNic {
nodeType = nodeType;
d2dCapable = d2dCapable;
@display ("p=324.684,406.116"0;
}
```

in veins_hetvnet.ned/Car.ned

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to port all of `veins_hetvnet` to the newer SimuLTE version (which will be very time intensive), you will need to use the SimuLTE version it was written for.